# How do I check I've removed all python3 before a fresh brew install?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

Apologies for the noob question, just getting my feet wet into coding with macOS's terminal and Python.

I'm trying to fully remove python 3.8 (installed from python.org's package), then create a fresh install with Homebrew (I've been told this is the way).  My approach wasn't thorough.  I started by using an app removal program (CleanMyMac) and realized it did a poor job.  There were files & directories lingering, so I started deleting them through the terminal and have slowly realized just how out of hand this has become.

Ex., removed:

```
/Applications/Python3.8
/Users/5pacemanSpiff/library/caches/com.apple.python
/Library/Python/3.8
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/org.python.idle.sfl
/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.ApplicationRecentDocuments/org.python.pythonlauncher.sfl
/Library/Saved Application State/org.python.PythonLauncher.savedState
/Library/Saved Application State/org.python.IDLE.savedState
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pydoc3
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pydoc3.8
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3.8
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-3.8.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonFramework-3.8.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-3.8.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonApplications-3.8.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonFramework-3.8.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonUnixTools-3.8.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonApplications-3.8.plist
/private/var/db/receipts/org.python.Python.PythonDocumentation-3.8.plist
```

Should I remove files/directories like the following and how do I determine what others should be removed?

```
/library/developer/commandlinetools/usr/bin/pip3
```

How can I check if I've removed all files necessary to prevent conflicts with a brew install?

Comment: Just ```brew uninstall python``` or ```brew remove python``` should work. Change ```python``` to ```python3``` if python is not recognized.

Comment: Not sure you really needed to do this, unless you are very concerned about space usage.  Brew puts its `/usr/local/bin` binaries *before* Apple directories in the`PATH` so its Python will be found first and will not conflict.